# Lessen Duplication of Dispatching in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a action called `saveThing`. In it, I have parameters, `thingNoErrors` and `thingWithErrors` . I have an `if statement` that if `thingNoErrors` has a value, then you only call the API. My problem is I don't want to repeat the dispatch of `constants.SUCCESSFUL` and the `callback` just to lessen the code and avoid repetition. Is there a way to better way to revise it?

```
export const saveThing =
  ({ thingNoErrors = [], thingWithErrors = [], callback = () => {} }) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.REQUESTING,
      });

      if (thingNoErrors?.length > 0) {
        let formData = new FormData();

        Object.keys(thingNoErrors).forEach((fieldName) => {
          formData.append(
            thingNoErrors[fieldName]?.name,
            thingNoErrors[fieldName]?.file
          );
        });

        const response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/sample/api`, formData);

        dispatch({
          type: constants.SUCCESSFUL,
          payload: {
            data: [...response.data, ...thingWithErrors],
          },
        });

        callback('success')
      }

      dispatch({
        type: constants.SUCCESSFUL,
        payload: {
          data: thingWithErrors,
        },
      });

      callback('success')
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: constants.ERROR,
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could factor out/declare the "response" variable to be *outside* the if-conditional block, and shallow merge it into the `data` array to allow for the single successful action dispatch.

```
export const saveThing = ({
  thingNoErrors = [],
  thingWithErrors = [],
  callback = () => {},
}) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: constants.REQUESTING });

    let response;

    if (thingNoErrors?.length) {
      let formData = new FormData();

      Object.keys(thingNoErrors).forEach((fieldName) => {
        formData.append(
          thingNoErrors[fieldName]?.name,
          thingNoErrors[fieldName]?.file
        );
      });

      response = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/sample/api`, formData);
    }

    dispatch({
      type: constants.SUCCESSFUL,
      payload: {
        data: [...(response?.data || []), ...thingWithErrors],
      },
    });

    callback('success');
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: constants.ERROR });
  }
};
```